# Search bar for website that match any word from search bar to the database column

Tags: php

I want to create a search bar for a website that matches one, two, or any of the input words against a database column (named title).

For example, if I type in "MY NAME IS CHETAN FROM INDIA", I would want a successful match against title=" I AM LIVING IN **INDIA**" (via the match on "INDIA".)

How can I design such a query?

Some more examples: right now, if I search for "I like to play" then my query only matches with the database row "I like to play cricket everyday " but not with "you are like my brother". I want to match it also with rows "I like football matches" or "I play everyday " or "you are like my brother"

```
<form action="search.php" role="search" method="GET">
     <input type="text" name="searchbox">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
</form>
$search = strtolower($_GET['searchbox']);
$search_exploded = explode ( " ", $search );
$construct = '';
foreach( $search_exploded as $search_each ) {
    if(!in_array($search_each, $commonwords)){
        $construct .="AND title LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
    }
}
$construct="SELECT * FROM vdo WHERE 1 $construct LIMIT 60";
$query=mysqli_query($con1,$construct);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $title=$row['title'];
    echo $title;
}
```

Comment: Change your query to be `OR` instead of `AND`. However, a bigger issue with your code is that you are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries like that. Granted, you reduce the risk since you're exploding the search term, but if the search contains a `'` for example, your query will break. You should simply _never_ trust user data.

Comment: using OR insted of and did not show any specific result it shows all content from database

Comment: That's because you have the `WHERE 1` in the beginning, which will always be true and since you're using `OR`, only one of the statements needs to be true for the row to be selected. Remove the `1` and only add the `1` if no words were entered, if you then want to select all rows.

Comment: sir can you please edit correct code using OR  and answer full code..thnx in advance coz it gives error as  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Comment: I've pointed you in the right direction. Unfortunately, I don't have time to fix your code, considering that you should change it to use prepared statements as well. I would also suggest moving to PDO instead of MySQLi here, since that would make it _much_ easier to use a dynamic amount of placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `MYSQL FULLTEXT_SEARCH` method.

Documentation:-
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Example:-

**TABLE**

```
|id|columntosearch|
|2 | You can search any word|
|3 | Yes word is the word|
|4 | fourth row|

MySQL> SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE MATCH(`columntosearch`) AGAINST('word' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

**Output**

```
|id| columntosearch
|2 | You can search any word
|3 | Yes word is the word
```